# How to perform a cascaded merge against child of new entity with JPA and Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

This question relates to managing id numbers to ensure that I don't end up with duplicate identities on my person's table. It is a springboot project with MySQL database.

Some background:

I have an HTML form for submitting an "episode". Each episode contains "persons" and has a relationship to "persons" of ManyToMany.

"episodes" are entered and submitted into the database (db1) by field staff. A few hours later the episode is manually entered into a second database (db2) by BackOffice staff.

On my spring attached database (db1) I have a persons table which has a native auto generated id field. db1 also has a id2 field - which records the unique id for the person from db2.

Field staff do not always have access to id2 when they enter a episode, but BackOffice staff do.

When I save a new "episode" I need the save method to check if person id2 exists in the database and perform an update on person (not create new).

Then delete the duplicate person.

Episode entity:

```
@Entity
public class Episode {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
...
@Column(name="start_date")
@DateTimeFormat (pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
private Date start_date;
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinTable(name = "episode_person", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "episode_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<Person> persons;
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
//@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private Address address;
```

Person Entity

```
@Entity
public class Person {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private Long id2;
private String surname;
private String firstname;
private String phoneHome;
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/mm/yyyy")
private Date dob;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "persons", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
private List<Episode> episodes;
```

EpisodeServiceImpl

```
@Override
@Transactional
public Episode saveEpisode(Episode episode) {
    List mergedPeople = personService.mergeDetachedWithAttached( episode.getPersons() );
    episode.setPersons( mergedPeople );
    return episodeRepository.save(episode);
}
```

PersonServiceImpl

```
    @Transactional
@Override
public List mergeDetachedWithAttached(List<Person> people) {
    final List<Person> results = new ArrayList<>();
    if ( people != null && !people.isEmpty() ) {

        // loop over every person
        for (Person person : people) {

            // for current person try to retrieve from db via Id2
            Person db2Person = personRepository.findById2( person.getId2() );

            // if a person was retrieved use them instead of submitted person
            if (db2Person != null ) {
                System.out.println("A matching person was found in the db using id2 - this is the person that will be added");
                results.add(db2Person);
            } else {
                results.add(person);
            }
        }
    }
    return results;
```

The way this is written at the moment when ever a new episode is submitted I create new person(s) even if I successfully looked them up from db1 using id2 and added them to the episode.

How can I handle this so that:

I can merge duplicate identities based on comparing id2. The joining table that holds episode_id and person_id will also need to be updated where a id is deleted after a merge.

Comment: @vladmihalcea the question has two parts (1) about cascading updates and (2) merging. The essence of the merging question is : id2 tracks unique people. As id2 is not always available at the beginning of the process when episode is first submitted. Thus it is possible that when id2 is eventually entered it may be found the person already exist in db1 (by looking up id2). At this point I need to update the existing db1 person with any new details and delete the duplicate person. (including updating the join table episode_person).

Comment: Check-then-act logic is always susceptible to concurrency issues. What if after the check, some concurrent thread already inserts the entity in question. The only way to do it properly is with UPSERT.

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier if you replace the `@ManyToMany` association with 2 bidirectional `@OneToMany` associations, meaning that you map the association table as well.

This way, considering that you have those duplicated `Episode` or `Person` entities, you can easily move the joined association by simply adjusting the `@ManyToOne` associations on the association entity. As for the duplicated `Episode` or `Person` you can either use UPSERT as explained below, or do a manual merging after the entries are added to the DB by the batch process.

Typically, when you have multiple nodes that running concurrently, you can use the database UPSERT or MERGE operation.

You could combine the UPSERT with Hibernate [`@SqlInsert` annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#annotations-hibernate-sqlinsert).

To handle the FK updates, you'd need to use the FK ON DELETE CASCADE strategy.